# Weird string concatenate related to arabic symbol C#

Tags: c#

HI,

I'm trying to build up a number format for currency data.

If the symbol is $:
     the result of   $ + #,##0.0000  is $#,##0.0000
 -> it's good.

But if the symbol is ر.س  (Saudi Arabia currency symbol)
     the result is    #,##000ر.س    ~0  s0
Even on this website I cannot write the correct result string.
My expected result is just place the symbol right the same like any other, but every time I try it always turn to a weird character order.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of issues in bidirectional Unicode character ordering. Try setting the text direction of the Label/TextBox/whatever you are putting the string into to right-to-left.